# Dygraph - how to change language in date format?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I would like to use dygraph combined (dygraph.com) in one of my projects. The problem is, that it shows date (on X axis) in eanglish:

Jan 01, Feb 01, Apr 01, etc.

and I want to display it in some other language (like Polish) for example:

Sty 01, Lut 01, Mar 01, etc.

Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the options is harder because you have to considerer the granularity, but you can edit [dygraph-combined.js](http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js) changing the names of months and days, for example, replace text "Jan" with "Sty" and so on, then save and use it

you will get the same behavior with your language.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the axisLabelFormatter function to format the date any way you want. For other languages, set up arrays of the day names and month names (sorry i don't know polish):

```
var d_names = ['nie','pon','wto','sro','czw','pia','sob'];
var m_names = ['stycz','luty','mar','kwiec','maj','czerw','lip','sierp','wrzes','pazdz','listop','grudz'];
```

Then reference these arrays in the formatter function:

```
axisLabelFormatter: function(d, gran) {
        var curr_day  = d_names[d.getDay()];
        var curr_month = m_names[d.getMonth()];
        return curr_day + "<br /> "
        + curr_month + ' ' 
        + Dygraph.zeropad(d.getDate()) 
        ;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/SdLHb/8/)**

Comment: Thanks! But Cephei solution (below) is exactly what I need.