# change the language of the legend in dygraph in r

Tags: javascript, r, legend, dygraphs

I have done this. Edited
the dygraph-combined.js changing the names of months and days, for example, replace text "Oct" with "Okt" and so on, to change the language of the date format ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173205/10994402). This works well but the legend is still in english . How do I change this ? Could someone please give me a hint ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used a legend formatter with some textarrays to set up language specific labels.
var d_names = [ ... the seven days ];
var m_names = [ ... the twelve months ];

```
x:{axisLabelFormatter:function(d,gran){
    var curr_month=m_names[d.getMonth()];
    var curr_day=d_names[d.getDay()];
    var Hrs=d.getHours();
    var Minuten=d.getMinutes();
    var Mins=((Minuten<10)?"0"+Minuten:Minuten);
    return curr_day+" "+d.getDate()+"/"+curr_month+" "+Hrs+":"+ Mins);
    },},
```

based on granularity you might consider to have different/shorter strings returned